# What is the Most Efficient Way to Compute the (euclidean) Distance of the Nearest Neighbor in a List of (x,y,z) points?

Tags: python, knn, nearest-neighbor, euclidean-distance

What is the most efficient way compute (euclidean) distance of the nearest neighbor for each point in an array?

I have a list of 100k (X,Y,Z) points and I would like to compute a list of nearest neighbor distances. The index of the distance would correspond to the index of the point.

I've looked into PYOD and sklearn neighbors, but those seem to require "teaching". I think my problem is simpler than that. For each point: find nearest neighbor, compute distance.

Example data:

```
points = [
     (0             0   1322.1695
      0.006711111   0   1322.1696
      0.026844444   0   1322.1697
      0.0604        0   1322.1649
      0.107377778   0   1322.1651
      0.167777778   0   1322.1634
      0.2416        0   1322.1629
      0.328844444   0   1322.1631
      0.429511111   0   1322.1627...)]
```

compute k = 1 nearest neighbor distances

result format:

```
results = [nearest neighbor distance]
```

example results:

```
results = [
0.005939372
0.005939372
0.017815632
0.030118587
0.041569616
0.053475883
0.065324964
0.077200014
0.089077602)
]
```

UPDATE:

I've implemented two of the approaches suggested.

1. Use the scipy.spatial.cdist to compute the full distances matrices
2. Use a nearest X neighbors in radius R to find subset of neighbor distances for every point and return the smallest.

Results are that Method 2 is faster than Method 1 but took a lot more effort to implement (makes sense).

It seems the limiting factor for Method 1 is the memory needed to run the full computation, especially when my data set is approaching 10^5 (x, y, z) points. For my data set of 23k points, it takes ~ 100 seconds to capture the minimum distances.

For method 2, the speed scales as n_radius^2. That is, "neighbor radius squared", which really means that the algorithm scales ~ linearly with number of included neighbors. Using a Radius of ~ 5 (more than enough given application) it took 5 seconds, for the set of 23k points, to provide a list of mins in the same order as the point_list themselves. The difference matrix between the "exact solution" and Method 2 is basically zero.

Thanks for everyones' help!

Comment: Do you know what the values of these distances is supposed to be? Would help to have an expected output.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: The distance to the centroid? between all points?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: d_kennetz Yes. I have the outputs in JMP. Looking to port this to python.

Comment: Question is how to find distance to single nearest neighbor for each point in array. That is, for each point: find nearest neighbor, output distance. I can do this via brute force, but figure there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: yeah I saw that you wrote that. I think you should probably include what the outputs should be (numerical values) if you have them so we can replicate what you desire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to Caleb's answer, but you could stop the iterative loop if you get a distance greater than some previous minimum distance (sorry - no code).

I used to program video games. It would take too much CPU to calculate the actual distance between two points. What we did was divide the "screen" into larger Cartesian squares and avoid the actual distance calculation if the Delta-X or Delta-Y was "too far away" - That's just subtraction, so maybe something like that to qualify where the actual Eucledian distance metric calculation is needed (extend to n-dimensions as needed)?

EDIT - expanding "too far away" candidate pair selection comments.
For brevity, I'll assume a 2-D landscape.
Take the point of interest (X0,Y0) and "draw" an nxn square around that point, with (X0,Y0) at the origin.

Go through the initial list of points and form a list of candidate points that are within that square. While doing that, if the DeltaX [ABS(Xi-X0)] is outside of the square, there is no need to calculate the DeltaY.

If there are no candidate points, make the square larger and iterate.

If there is exactly one candidate point and it is within the radius of the circle incribed by the square, that is your minimum.

If there are "too many" candidates, make the square smaller, *but you only need to reexamine the candidate list from this iteration, not all the points.*

If there are not "too many" candidates, then calculate the distance for that list. When doing so, first calculate DeltaX^2 + DeltaY^2 for the first candidate. If for subsequent candidates the DetlaX^2 is greater than the minumin so far, no need to calculate the DeltaY^2.

The minimum from that calculation is the minimum if it is within the radius of the circle inscribed by the square.

If not, you need to go back to a previous candidate list that includes points within the circle that has the radius of that minimum. For example, if you ended with one candidate in a 2x2 square that happened to be on the vertex X=1, Y=1, distance/radius would be SQRT(2). So go back to a previous candidate list that has a square greated or equal to 2xSQRT(2).

If warranted, generate a new candidate list that only includes points withing the +/- SQRT(2) square.
Calculate distance for those candidate points as described above - omitting any that exceed the minimum calcluated so far.

No need to do the square root of the sum of the Delta^2 until you have only one candidate.

How to size the initial square, or if it should be a rectangle, and how to increase or decrease the size of the square/rectangle could be influenced by application knowledge of the data distribution.

I would consider recursive algorithms for some of this if the language you are using supports that.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I would expect something like this to be the best possible approach. The distance algo may still scale as n^2 but if you could reduce the data set for each point to like the 10 or even 100 surrounding points as well as don't recalculate the same stuff multiple times (just look it up), then the speed may be limited by sorting and looking up previous values. Would probably scale like nlog n after that.

Comment: Expanded my original answer to be more clear on candidate point selection.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
from scipy.spatial import distance

A = (0.003467119 ,0.01422762 ,0.0101960126)
B = (0.007279433  ,0.01651597  ,0.0045558849)
C = (0.005392258  ,0.02149997  ,0.0177409387)
D = (0.017898802  ,0.02790659  ,0.0006487222)
E = (0.013564214  ,0.01835688  ,0.0008102952)
F = (0.013375397  ,0.02210725 ,0.0286032185)

points = [A, B, C, D, E, F]
results = []
for point in points:
    distances = [{'point':point, 'neighbor':p, 'd':distance.euclidean(point, p)} for p in points if p != point]
    results.append(min(distances, key=lambda k:k['d']))
```

results will be a list of objects, like this:

```
results = [
    {'point':(x1, y1, z1), 'neighbor':(x2, y2, z2), 'd':"distance from point to neighbor"},
...]
```

Where `point` is the reference point and `neighbor` is point's closest neighbor.

Comment: Thanks Caleb. This would work though is there a less brute force approach? This would have a scaling of > N^2 because each point calcs distances then finds min for all points in array. Data size is close to 10^5. I was thinking to use a k = 1 NN or maybe LOF approach to do this.

Comment: @ColePierson There probably is a more efficient approach, but I don't know much about this.  Also, I updated your question to make it clear that you are looking for *the most efficient* approach, and not just any old approach (like mine).  I'd recommending reviewing it to make sure I didn't change the meaning of your answer.

Comment: @ColePierson Generally, if you are looking for *the most efficient way to do x*, you should emphasize that in your question so ignorant people (like me) don't give you sub-optimal solutions.

Comment: Thanks @CalebGoodman. Not ignorant at all. In fact, I will probably use it unless a clear winner emerges. I just know that there are algorithms that are designed to optimize this type of calc and it would be a great learning experience to implement that type of solution.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest option available to you may be [`scipy.spatial.distance.cdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html), which finds the pairwise distances between all of the points in its input. While finding all of those distances may not be the fastest algorithm to find the nearest neighbors, `cdist` is implemented in C, so it is likely run faster than anything you try in Python.

```
import scipy as sp
import scipy.spatial
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

points = sp.array(...)
distances = sp.spatial.distance.cdist(points)

# An element is not its own nearest neighbor
sp.fill_diagonal(distances, sp.inf)

# Find the index of each element's nearest neighbor
mins = distances.argmin(0)

# Extract the nearest neighbors from the data by row indexing
nearest_neighbors = points[mins, :]

#  Put the arrays in the specified shape
results = np.stack((points, nearest_neighbors), 1)
```

You could theoretically make this run faster (mostly by combining all of the steps into one algorithm), but unless you're writing in C, you won't be able to compete with SciPy/NumPy.

(`cdist` runs in Θ(n<sup>2</sup>) time (if the size of each point is fixed), and every other part of the algorithm in O(n) time, so even if you did try to optimize the code in Python, you wouldn't notice the change for small amounts of data, and the improvements would be overshadowed by `cdist` for more data.)